# Redirecting to same page in different context

Tags: php, redirect

I have made a page in php which makes xml out of the form filled by the user. Thus, after submission the page sends code to different page. I want to return to the previous page so as to ask user to input more data for xml. Can it be redirected with different context everytime, i.e. Can it store the no. of forms user has filled and still get back to the same page?

Comment: Sure you can do this. Add parameters to the redirect link or store the needed values in the session / cookies.

Comment: If you use the $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] link in the form action, then you can send the form datas to the same PHP script, and no need redirect. The another solution is, send the form datas via AJAX, and the form page also stays in place.